# Space Complexity for code snippet "for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { int x = 10 } ; "

Tags: c, space-complexity

Regarding [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128990/what-will-be-space-complexity-for-snippet-fori-1-to-n-int-x-10) question, for code snippet

```
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
       int x = 10;
```

It is written there in the comment section that space complexity will be O(1). According to me, it should be O(n).

**My Reasoning :** Variable "x" should not be destroyed after each iteration of "for" loop. According to the scope rules, variable "x" can't be accessed outside the "for" loop because it is declared,defined and initialized in a block "{}" but this variable "x" is local to the function "main()" (Assuming, it is a C code and it is written in main()), So, [lifetime](https://www.inf.unibz.it/%7Ecalvanese/teaching/04-05-ip/lecture-notes/uni03/node17.html) of variable "x" will be there till the program gets terminated because activation record(stack frame) of function "main()" will be removed at the end of the program. As lifetime of "x" remains till the program ends, So, it means memory space for "x" will also be created after each iteration of "for" loop and should not be reused. So, there will be "n" copies of variable "x" in activation record of main().
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The same memory is used for `x` in every iteration. It doesn't need to save the previous value, so it can reuse it.

Comment: @Barmar, can you please tell me what is wrong in my reasoning ? If I write x=10; inside for loop and write int x; outside for loop and in main() then it will be O(1). Should not memory space be created in each iteration of for loop ?

Comment: yes, but the memory is reclaimed each time as well. There's never more than one `x` at a time.

Comment: Got it. Thank you @Barmar.

Answer (score 1):

> It is written there in the comment section that space complexity will be O(1). According to me, it should be O(n).

For that code the time complexity is O(n), space complexity is O(1) - you don't use any extra space, regardless of `n` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're missing is that scopes don't necessarily have to be formed using braces. The code you've shown is exactly equivalent to:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    int x = 10;
}
```

The lack of braces doesn't matter. The body of the for loop still forms its own scope and `x` is declared inside it.